# How to trigger click event in Selenium for a link, when used with Java driver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-rc

I used the

```
selenium.click("link=Sign In");
```

And I tried using the

```
selenium.click(".//*[@id='global-signin']/a");
```

Both didn't yield me the result.

I am getting the error as below :-

> Element Link="Sign In" not found error.

Code:

```
package package1_IdentifyPageOpened;


import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
//import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PublicClass3 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.washingtonpost.com/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTt4() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("link=Sign In");
        selenium.type("name=MemberName", "mcXXX@gmail.com");
        selenium.type("name=Password", "PPP@123");
        selenium.click("name=submit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Failure Trace:

```
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element link=Sign
 In not found   at
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
    at
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:106)
    at
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.click(DefaultSelenium.java:193)
    at
 package1_IdentifyPageOpened.PublicClass3.testTt4(PublicClass3.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
 org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at
 org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at
 org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)    at
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)    at
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)    at
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)   at
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)  at
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Isn't the link hidden from Selenium in a `frame` or `iframe` element? In that case, you need to [select the frame](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectFrame%28java.lang.String%29) before clicking the link. If not, please show us a minimal (but reproducable) piece of the HTML so we can help you.

Comment: @A.J have included code...pls. see now, and provide your comment and suggestions...

Comment: @Slanec pls. look now and provide your suggestion pls..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also met the same problem before and 'Element not found' problem is frequently happening in selenium.The  possible causes to this problem are as follows:

1. when you execute "click element",however the element has not show in the page,maybe its in the procedding of loading,then selenium will throw a exception: element not found.
2. the element's identity is wrong,maybe a spelling error or the selenium does not support the identity way.

I visited the website you tested,http://www.washingtonpost.com

Test-Case recorded by `SeleniumIDE` always does not work when you export as  Java.

Here is my code:

```java
 public class Website extends SeleneseTestBase {
     @BeforeMethod
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
         selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.washingtonpost.com/");
         selenium.start();
     }

     @Test
     public void testWebsite() throws Exception {
         selenium.open("/");
         waitFor("link=Sign In");
         waitSecomd(3);
         selenium.click("link=Sign In");
         selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
         selenium.type("name=MemberName", "adasf@gmail.com");
         selenium.type("name=Password", "adfasd");
         selenium.click("name=submit");
         selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
     }

     @AfterMethod
     public void tearDown() throws Exception {
         selenium.stop();
     }
     public void waitFor(String locator) throws Exception {
         for (int second = 0;; second++) {
             if (second >= 60)
                 fail("timeout");
             try {
                 if (selenium.isVisible(locator))
                     break;
             } catch (Exception e) {}
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
     }


     public void waitSecomd(int n) throws Exception {
         for (int second = 0;; second++) {
             if (second >= 60)
                 fail("timeout");
             try {
                 if (second > n - 1)
                     break;
             } catch (Exception e) {}
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution...I guess you are using a different version of Selenium...I am using 2.2...waitFor method is not found...Can you please provide the latest method...

Comment: my God! waitFor() method is provided by myself,it is  not the selenium API.and I provided the method in my code,how you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` element is created dynamically (and in a bad way - it shows up after a long time) and Selenium can't find it. If you look into the source code of the page, you can only see

```
<div id="utility-wrapper" data-tracking-type="utility">
    <ul id="utility-links" class="inline-list">  
        <li id="global-signin" style="min-width:32px;"></li>
```

---

The cause is in one of the js files where the Sign In link is created as follows:

```
I.innerHTML = '<a href="' + D + "...a loong piece of URL..." + H + '">Sign In</a>';
```

Selenium can find a dynamically created element, but only after it is created, not before.

The first solution that comes to head, `selenium.click("id=global-signin")` doesn't work because the element is found and clicked, but doesn't yet contain the actual link (which is created by js some time later).

---

The solution is to wait for the element to show up:

```
long targetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;  // 10 seconds from now
boolean found = false;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < targetTime && !found) {
    if (selenium.isElementPresent("link=Sign In")) {
        selenium.click("link=Sign In");
        found = true;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    throw new SeleniumException("Element not found!");
}
```

you can even write your own `click(String)` method (and others too, it's possible either the easy way via code repetition, or the harder but nicer way via the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)) that incorporates this for use in every search.

In [Selenium 2 (WebDriver)](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) it would be much easier to do via [Implicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits):

```
// open Firefox
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// set the Implicit wait to 10 seconds
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.washingtonpost.com/");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
```

Comment: I did check with id=global-signin previously and also,waiting time , it didn't work for me, initially...is it working from your end?

Comment: Edited. A lot. You should seriously consider switching to WebDriver. But the Selenium solution now works for me, too. Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: thanks for making it easier...The first method,  you gave via exception is not working...Its throwing exception....The second method, via WebDriver is working....There is a typo in your second solution...You left Driver.findElement...Thanks !!

Comment: Oh, so you could go for WebDriver? Cool. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

This was tough - the problem I had was on the second page - Selenium could not enter any data into the form unless I selected a target locator first. Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LoginTest {

    private static final String USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final int PAUSE = 10;

    @Test
    public void testWebsiteTwo() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(PAUSE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.washingtonpost.com/");
        WebElement signin = driver.findElement(By
                .cssSelector("li#global-signin a"));
        signin.click();

        // this line is crucial so that Selenium can enter the username / password

        WebDriver.TargetLocator locator = driver.switchTo();
        locator.frame(0);
        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#username"));
        name.sendKeys(USERNAME);
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#password"));
        password.sendKeys(PASSWORD);
        WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form[name=form]"));
        form.submit();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks !! :) Your solution looks neat and I will definitely look into it and get back..:)